# Adding specific content into empty LinearLayout causing error

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make custom `BottomSheet` layout which will serve as a base design. It has stylized title and then there is content container which is empty `LinearLayout`. What I want to do is to add custom content into this `LinearLayout` dynamically.

Code:

```
protected fun setContent(content: ViewGroup){
        bottomSheetParent.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.contentContainer).also {
            it.removeAllViews()
            it.addView(content)
        }
}
```

This is working fine with my custom `Dialog` layout where I can dynamically add content into `Dialog` window, but for some reason for `BottomSheet` its causing exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

What does it mean child has parent? I know parent of this `BottomSheet` layout has title `TextView` and container for content. Removing all `Views` from its parent will completely destroy empty template.

Here is `bottomSheetParent`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dialog_top">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/dialog_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dialog_bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's to do with `content` having a parent already. You're trying to add it as a child of `bottomSheetParent` but it's already a child of something else. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Yes thanks I found out parent of that layout is inside another LinearLayout. Removing it makes it work